# Word between 9-10 characters, of which 0-2 are numbers

Tags: regex

http://regexr.com?32uvo

What I currently have:

```
\b(?=[A-Z\d]{10})(?:[A-Z]*\d){0,2}[A-Z]*\b
```

This would only match a string with a length of 10. I would like to change it to between 9 and 10 characters, where 2 can be numbers. Why doesn't this work?

```
\b(?=[A-Z\d]{9,10})(?:[A-Z]*\d){0,2}[A-Z]*\b
```

AFAIK, `{9,10}` should be the length interval.

Comment: Your Regexr example matches "satellite" if I turn on case-insensitivity.

Comment: which language r u using..`regex` implementation differs from language to language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close

```
 \b(?=[A-Z\d]{9,10}\b)(?:[A-Z]*\d){0,2}[A-Z]*\b
                   --            
                    |->you missed this
```

try it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

So this regex would match a word that contains 9 to 10 characters[upper case and digits] that contain 1 to 2 digits

---

if you want to match the whole string you better use `^`(start of the string) and `$`(end of the string)

Comment: I don't think it is _required_ to contain two digits, just that it is allowed to contain up to two digits.

Comment: @Wiseguy opps i thought he want to match exactly 2 digits..edited..;)

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Okay, now you are requiring one or two digits. I don't think any digits are required. (See question which has `{0,2}`, not `{1,2}`.)

Comment: @Wiseguy but his question asks `1-2 numbers`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ Oh, I see. I didn't notice that the title seemingly conflicts with the body of the question.

Comment: As @Wiseguy said, up to 2 digits. So its actually 0-2. Sorry for being unclear. `{0,2}` doesnt seem to work